# How do I change images with buttons in .vb?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm coding a turn-based battle game and I cannot figure out how to make a button show a certain image on a different form on visual basic. This is my code if it helps:

`Form1.plyrs_sprite = Image.FromFile`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just create a new form with just the desired image and open it up when the button is pressed e.g. the new picture is in `form3`

```
me.hide()
form3.show()
```

Comment: i would like to keep the forms to a minimal, and i need to put multiple things on the same form